# Add Program Exception to Windows Firewall still does not allow connections

Tags: .net, windows, wcf, exception, firewall

I can't seem the get a program exception to work in Windows Firewall for my DotNet WCF executable.  I have this command:

```
netsh.exe advfirewall firewall add rule name="MyApp Rule" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP program="c:\myapp\myapp.exe"
```

However, I still cannot connect from a remote computer (on the same subnet).  It works fine if I specify an exact port number, for example:

```
netsh.exe advfirewall firewall add rule name="MyApp Rule" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=12345
```

I have tried it from both the Command Line and the Firewall Exception GUI.

I have tried on several different machines with several different operating systems including 2008R2 and 2012R2.

Is there some special trick I need to know?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I learned that the WCF listeners run in the System context not in the application's context so that was the reason specifying the WCF executable did not work.  Interestingly if I specify program=system, that works.